# How can I get CSS flex items to position into space above?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

[image: Image of flex items]

How can I get the flex items to take up the space above them as I've shown in the image above?

Here's my code:

```html
<ul class="list-container">
  <li v-for="hero in heroes" :key="hero.id" class="hero-list-card">
    <router-link
      :to="{ name: 'Hero', params: { name: slugify(hero.name), id: hero.id} }"
      data-testid="hero-name">
      <img :src="`${hero.thumbnail.path}.${hero.thumbnail.extension}`" alt="">

      <div class="text">
        <p class="description heading four">{{ hero.name }}</p>
        <img class="icon" src="@/assets/icons/arrow-right.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
  .list-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .comic-list-card,
  .hero-list-card {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can add align-self: stretch; to the items and they would all get the same height, which would force them to take up the remaining space adjacent to each item.

Comment: That is one option, but I would rather each item only take up the height it creates. All the images are different sizes, and I don't want any of the cards to have a big area of blue where the text is to make up the height difference. I guess the look I want to achieve is more of a 'mosaic' kind of thing.